# как убрать кнопку Cancel из ConfirmDialog в Java

Tags: java

Создаю в Java окно `ConfirmDialog("какой-то текст")`. В появившемся окошке будет "какой-то текст", и внизу 3 кнопки: "Yes", "No", "Cancel". Суть задания в том, чтобы убрать кнопку "Cancel", чтобы остались только "Yes" и "No". Не знаю, как это сделать, нигде пока ничего толкового не нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

Не забывайте читать [мануалы от Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), там есть подробные примеры:

```
final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(
    "Don't forget to read manuals ;)",
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уважаемый Denis, спасибо за ответ. Только вот привожу задание дословно: "Усложнённое задание: убрать кнопку “Cancel” в диалоговом окне из трёх кнопок (найти эту информацию и разобраться самостоятельно)." Не знаю, зачем это, но так написано, а разобраться в этом не могу.

Comment: @Анд Получается, вы провалили задание - не разобрались самостоятельно.

Comment: @Анд попробуйте тогда http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334931/disable-ok-button-on-joptionpane-dialog-until-user-gives-an-input

Comment: @Denis, попробовал. Не уверен, что это именно то, что нужно, свяжусь с преподавателем, попрошу его объяснить, что имелось в виду. Но всё равно спасибо Вам большое за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

вот полезная ссылка, но если вкратце у тебя будет такой вот код:

```
int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
  frame, // собственно фрейм
  "Would you like green eggs and ham?",  //вопрос
  "An Inane Question",  //заголовок
   JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION  //эта строчка указывает что кнопка Cancel не используется
);`
```